# Find the smallest positive number which when increased by 17, is exactly divisible by both 520 and 468.

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

I actually know the answer. It is just finding the LCM. But when I checked with my calculator, it showed me a decimal number.
The method I followed was to find LCM and subtract 17 from it. Is my method correct? Or should I go with any better method? If yes, please help me.

Comment: We have no idea if your method is correct since you don't tell us what it is.  Please edit your post to include your solution.  Also: I assume you mean to restrict to the natural numbers, so $(-520\times 468-17)$ and such  wouldn't be allowed, but you should say so.

Comment: Oh my bad... I forgot to mention there, My method is to find the LCM and subtract 17 from it...

Comment: 520 is 520 and 468 is 468. There is no sign inversion or something other...

Comment: What did you enter in your calculator and what is it showing?

Comment: I entered the lcm subracted by 17 and divided by 468(lcm-17/468) and it shows me decimal

Comment: $468,520\mid x\!+\!17\iff \color{#c00}{4680}\mid x\!+\!17\iff x = -17\!+\!4680n = 4663,\, 9343,\ldots$ by $(468,520) = (-52,520) = 52,\,$ so $[468,520]= 468(520)/52 = \color{#c00}{4680}\ \ $

Comment: What does that 'n' mean?

Comment: U mean any variable?

Comment: $n$ denotes any integer.

Comment: Yes yes, got it...

Comment: Please delete the question since the math is a duplicate of many prior posts.

Comment: U mean many have already asked this question already?

Comment: Yes, there are many prior instances of such lcm problems. Nothing is new in this one.

Comment: Okok will delete it now..

Comment: But still i didnot get perfect ans..

Comment: The ans is still in decimals

Comment: Is it okay if it is in decimal?

Comment: ${\rm lcm} - 17 = 4680-17 = 4663$ is correct. There is no division involved.

Comment: Yes... To check my ans... i divided 4663 from 468, it gives out decimal ans...

Comment: From lcm to be more accurate

Comment: $468$ doesn't divide $x=4663,\,$ rather $468$ divides $x+17 = 4680\ \ $

Comment: Oh yes! I was really so dumb... Thanks for your help and spending ur time for me!!

Comment: Glad to see you got it.

Comment: Please don't forget to delete the question.